# How to sort map of objects by values ascendingly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the map posted below in the code section. what i want to achieve is, to sort the map according to the values ascendingly. so that, after sorting it,
i should the map sorted as shown in last section.

please let me know how can i achieve that.

**code**:

```
const obj1 = new Object();
const obj2 = new Object();
const obj3 = new Object();
const obj4 = new Object();

const map2 = {};
map2[obj1] = 10;
map2[obj2] = -20;
map2[obj3] = 0;
map2[obj4] = 40;
```

**after sorting**:

```
map2[obj2] = -20;
map2[obj3] = 0;
map2[obj1] = 10;
map2[obj4] = 40;
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you've done/tried to sort these objects?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: where you defined `map2`?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @N.Jadhav i modified the code. the map object is defined as follows  const map2 = {};

Comment: Then this wont work at all. Please provide a working example ([mcve]) if you want to get accurate answers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show what the `map2` variable is, but this could easily be handled by using native array methods, primarily [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
var map2 = new Map();
var obj1 = new Object();
var obj2 = new Object();
var obj3 = new Object();
var obj4 = new Object();
var map = [{
      obj: obj1,
      value: 10
    },
    {
      obj: obj2,
      value: -20
    },
    {
      obj: obj3,
      value: 0
    },
    {
      obj: obj4,
      value: 40
    },
  ]
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
  });
console.log(map);
```

Comment: i modified the code, the map object is modified as foolows :  const map2 = {};

Comment: @LetsamrIt `Type 'Object' cannot be used as an index type`. You can only use `number` and `string` type indexes on an object in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

if `map2` is a real `Map` it is as simple as:

```
 map2 = new Map([...map2.entries()].sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value));
```

Comment: i did not work. i modified the code above to Show the Definition of the map object..it is defined as follows: const map2 = {};